# Why doesn't RACObserve work with a RACSubject?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I have a couple places in my code where RACSubject is used instead of a normal RACSignal - typically these are for just event notifications with nil data. Anyways, one thing that stumped me along the way was trying to use the standard 'RACObserve - subscribeNext' on the subject and noticing that events weren't triggering the block.

Example using RACObserve & subscribeNext, similar to what one does with most standard RACSignals:

```
self.subjectOne = [RACSubject subject];

[RACObserve(self, subjectOne) subscribeNext:^(NSString * x) {
    NSLog(@"subjectOne: %@", x);
}];

[self.subjectOne sendNext:@"foo"];
[self.subjectOne sendNext:@"bar"];
```

results in the following output:

```
subjectOne: <RACSubject: 0x600000025700> name:
```

Why this instead of the two events?

NOTE: This was done using ReactiveCocoa 2.x

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using RACObserve on a RACSubject is that it's a macro for rac_valuesForKeyPath , and since there's no actual property that we're observing upon, we just see the initial side-effect get printed out and nothing else. If you breakpoint on the side-effect and look into subjectOne's "subscribers" property, you'll notice it doesn't even have any subscribers.

The solution is to just use subscribeNext without RACObserve.

Example using just subscribeNext:

```
self.subjectTwo = [RACSubject subject];

[self.subjectTwo subscribeNext:^(NSString * x) {
    NSLog(@"subjectTwo: %@", x);
}];

[self.subjectTwo sendNext:@"baz"];
[self.subjectTwo sendNext:@"cat"];
```

which results in the output:

```
subjectTwo: baz
subjectTwo: cat
```